# Finding specific child element in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to display a button, only if a json object contains the element `hidden: true`

However, the child elements are random.

```
draw": { "item": { "aircraft": { "hidden": false} }
draw": { "item": { "mounted": { "hidden": false} }
```

I am ng-repeating on this json, and since I don't know if it is `aircraft` or `mounted` I can't do something like this

```
<button ng-if="json.draw.item.next.hidden" />
```

**How can I say "Give me next element, without knowing the name"?**

Comment: Do you have any additional keys in `item`, other than the alternating `aircraft`, `mounted`, etc..?

Comment: @NewDev Yes. There can be many others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function like this:

```
function next(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    if(keys && keys.length > 0) return obj[keys[0]];
}
```

To use it:

```
next(json.draw.item).hidden
```

I test it with Angular.js it is Ok.([see also jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/30n944a3/))

See the snippet below.

```js
    function next(obj) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        if(keys && keys.length > 0) return obj[keys[0]];
    }
var draw1 = { "item": { "aircraft": { "hidden": false} }};
var draw2 = { "item": { "mounted": { "hidden": false} }};

document.write(next(draw1.item).hidden, '<br>');
document.write(next(draw2.item).hidden, '<br>');
```

Comment: Looks like this will work. Will give it a try. Thanks